# Can the ring data structure really be rotated?

Tags: rings

According to the [doc page](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Rings.html) describing Emacs Lisp's ring data structure, rings "support [...] rotation".  However, the word "rotate" appears nowhere else on the page, and none of the documented interface functions appear to perform it.

When I visit `ring.el` I find this in the header comments: `You can insert to, remove from, and rotate a ring.`  But again, the word "rotate" appears nowhere else in the file, and none of the functions defined there (some of which are not mentioned on the web page above) do rotation, as far as I can tell.

Am I missing something, or is the documentation wrong?

Obviously a one-place rotation in one particular direction is possible by doing `(ring-insert ring (ring-remove ring))`, and probably quite efficiently at that, but it seems like a far cry from "supporting" rotation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Functions `ring-next` and `ring-previous` do what you're asking, forward and backward, respectively.

It may not be obvious, but invoking `ring-next` on the last ring element cycles/rotates to the first element: wrap-around. Similarly, for `ring-previous` on the first element: it rotates to the last element.

I've filed Emacs [bug #42430](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=42430), to ask that the Elisp manual mention these functions. Thx.

---

To respond to your comment:

> simple indexed access modulo the length of the structure isn't what
> I'd call "rotation." To me, "you can rotate a ring" sounds like a
> mutating action that takes a distance N and has the effect that every
> element previously at index I is now at index I - N (modulo the length
> of the ring, of course). For example, given a ring with elements (1 2
> 3 4 5), I'd expect to have a function like (ring-rotate my-ring 2) and
> have the ring now contain (3 4 5 1 2).

No, that functionality is not offered as such, nor is it really needed, in general. It's not what was meant by "rotating" a ring. Perhaps that word isn't the best one for what is meant.

A ring in Elisp is not a list whose order matters. It's an instance of an abstract data type, if you like. This is true of `kill-ring`, `search-ring`, etc.

You have access to the ring elements by ring position, not implementation-list position, and you can change the position of a given element if you need to (as you suggested, with insertion and deletion). But the more typical operations are insertion at the head, deletion of a given element, accessing an element by its position/index, and accessing the next/previous ring element.

Something like this seems to be what you're looking for:

```lisp
(defun ring-rotate (ring &optional n)
  "Rotate RING N places.
N defaults to 1.
Moves ring element 2 to position 1, 3 to 2, 4 to 3, etc.
Moves element 1 to the end of the ring."
  (setq n  (or n  1))
  (let ((rng  ring))
    (dotimes (ii n rng)
      (ring-insert rng (ring-remove rng)))))
```

---

**Update:** FYI, Emacs bug #42430 was closed by the Emacs maintainer, with this comment:

> The manual says:
>
> > For yanking, one entry in the kill ring is designated the front of
> > the ring.  Some yank commands rotate the ring by designating a different
> > element as the front.  But this virtual rotation doesn’t change the list
> > itself—the most recent entry always comes first in the list.

> That's all.  I don't see any reason to expand this description of a
> "virtual rotation", since that would require bringing many internal
> details into the ELisp manual, with no apparent gain.

Comment: Not sure why you're directing me to `ring.el` when I already described having examined it.  But in any case, simple indexed access modulo the length of the structure isn't what I'd call "rotation."  To me, "you can rotate a ring" sounds like a mutating action that takes a distance N and has the effect that every element previously at index I is now at index I - N (modulo the length of the ring, of course).  For example, given a ring with elements `(1 2 3 4 5)`, I'd expect to have a function like `(ring-rotate my-ring 2)` and have the ring now contain `(3 4 5 1 2)`.